# Selecting N number of Random Records

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have **7200 rows of 29 users** who attended unique request tickets in 10 different categories.

Out of them, I need to select **N** records for each and every Users.

Conditions :

1. Out of N, 40 % rows should be those of a category **X**, Lets say Editorial.
2. Remaining 60 % rows should be those using other than Category **X**

Using sqlite, I handled so far by trying 'DISTINCT' but is there a way to achieve the above?

```
select distinct * from report 
where category <> 'Editorial'
and 
name in (select distinct name from report)
GROUP By name
LIMIT (select count(distinct name) from report)
```

edit : I'm using python for rest of all the above operations. As its a large data, I preferred sqlite.
If there's a way in python, I'm okie to learn about it.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a sqlite answer, but this question is tagged `python`. Is an answer using python in combination with sqlite ok?

Comment: Yes, I'm using sqlite in python for all these things.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using running count subqueries of two groupings: 1) all records by name and only Editorial category; and 2) all records by name and Non-Editorial category and filter for the 60% and 40%. Below assumes table has a unique identifier, `ID`. And replace the `N` in `WHERE` clause with actual number:

```
SELECT *    
FROM 
(
  SELECT Report.*

      (SELECT Count(*) FROM Report sub1
       WHERE sub1.Category = 'Editorial' AND Report.Category = 'Editorial'
       AND sub1.Name = Report.Name
       AND sub1.ID <= Report.ID) As EditorialRowNo

      (SELECT Count(*) FROM Report sub2
       WHERE sub2.Category <> 'Editorial' AND Report.Category <> 'Editorial'
       AND sub2.Name = Report.Name
       AND sub2.ID <= Report.ID) As NonEditorialRowNo

  FROM Report
) As dT

WHERE (dT.EditorialRowNo > 0 AND dT.EditorialRowNo <= 0.4 * N)
OR (dT.NonEditorialRowNo > 0 AND dT.NonEditorialRowNo <= 0.6 * N)
ORDER BY dT.Name, dT.Category
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, still a little confused about your spec. This code will run but I may not fully understand what you're looking for:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')

cur = conn.cursor()

count = cur.execute('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM book')

count = count.fetchone()[0]

total1 = int(count * 0.4)
total2 = int(count * 0.6)

results1 = cur.execute('SELECT users.id from users LIMIT ?',
                       (total1, )).fetchall()
results2 = cur.execute('SELECT users.id from users LIMIT ?',
                       (total2, )).fetchall()
```

Comment: @t-arboreus If so, How Can I do that for each and every users listed. .?

Comment: I've edited the response. Hope I understand what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, It throws  **ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type**.

Comment: Sorry, was being a bit pseudocody. You can't do multiplication in the tuple, just do that math outside and pass it in

Comment: yup, done that too. It still throws me the same error.
Could you make that one?

Comment: You shouldn't get errors with this, but you may need to adapt it to your needs or describe the problem more explicitly in the question, since I have the feeling I'm missing something you're looking for.